# Photo Mosaic in Mathematica: an example from 2008 doesn't work in Mathematica 8

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, backwards-compatibility, mathematica-8

I'm trying to get a Mathematica example working. It's the one on [Theo Gray's blog](http://blog.wolfram.com/2008/05/02/making-photo-mosaics/).

I think that Mathematica must have changed since he wrote that code (May 2008), since I'm unable to get anything reasonable out of it, despite changing nearly everything. Do I use ImageData instead of Import? Can anyone suggest a version of this code that works for Mathematica 8?

```
imagePool = 
 Map[With[{i = Import[#]}, {i, Mean[Flatten[N[i[[1, 1]]], 1]]}] &, 
  FileNames["Pool/*.jpg"]];
closeMatch[c_] := 
  RandomChoice[Take[SortBy[imagePool, Norm[c - #[[2]]] &], 20]][[1]];
Grid[Reverse[
  Map[closeMatch, Import["MendeleevIcon.tif"][[1, 1]], {2}]], 
  Spacings -> {0, 0}]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following works (Thanks to @yoda for pointing out the `Reverse[]` thing in the comments):

```
f = FileNames["*.jpg", {"c:\\test\\pool\\Pool"}];
m = Import["c:\\test\\pool\\Pool\\MendeleevIcon.tif"];
imagePool =
  Map[
   With[{i = Import[#]},
     {i, Mean[Flatten[ImageData@i, 1]]}] &, f];
closeMatch[c_] := 
  RandomChoice[Take[SortBy[imagePool, Norm[c - #[[2]]] &], 20]][[1]];
Grid[Map[closeMatch, ImageData@m, {2}], Spacings -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

Comment: Man, that southern hemisphere... always flipping things around

Comment: @yoda Is it upside-down? I can't make sense of anything in that image!

Comment: @yoda If it IS upside-down remove the `Reverse[]`

Comment: Yeah, it's upside down. The two dark patches on either side of the "Fm-Es-Fm---Es` strip in the middle of the lower third are the eyes. Starting with that, if you follow the darker images going upward from the left eye (picture left), it forms the shadow of the nose and eventually diverges in the top third fo become the moustache.

Comment: I saw the `Reverse`... It's less funny now, because I initially thought you had done it on purpose :)

Comment: Did something change between versions, or was it a path problem?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: I think that what has changed is that in Mathematica 8 (and possibly 7), `Import["file.jpg"]` returns an `Image[]` whereas in older versions it would return a `Graphics[Raster[]]`. You can still import a file as a `Graphics[Raster[]]` with `Import["file.jpg","Graphics"]

Comment: @Heike, IMHO, this should be spelled out in the answer.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe slightly more streamlined:

```
imagePool = Map[With[{i = Import[#]}, {i, N@Mean[Flatten[ImageData[i], 1]]}] &, 
   FileNames["Pool/*.jpg"]];

closeMatch[c_] := RandomChoice[
   Nearest[imagePool[[All, 2]] -> imagePool[[All, 1]], c, 20]]

ImageAssemble[Map[closeMatch, ImageData[Import["mendeleevIcon.tif"]], {2}]]
```

[image: mosaic]

**Edit**

The reason that the original code stopped working in version 8 is that up until version 6 of Mathematica, `Import["file.jpg"]` would return a `Graphics[Raster[]]` object. To extract the image data itself you could simply do `Import["file.jpg"][[1,1]]`. However, in version 8 (and I suspect version 7) raster images are imported as an `Image` by default which means that you need `ImageData` to extract the image data from the imported files. You can still import raster images as a `Graphics[Raster[]]` by using `Import["file.jpg","Graphics"]` so the original code should still work if you adapt the `Import` statements, but the advantage of using `Image` objects is that you can use functions such as `ImageAssemble` (plus a whole range of other image processing tools that comes with Mathematica 8).