# Photo Mosaic in Mathematica: an example from 2008 doesn't work in Mathematica 9

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mosaic

I'm trying to get a Mathematica example working. It's the one on [Theo Gray's blog](http://blog.wolfram.com/2008/05/02/making-photo-mosaics/). In Mathematica 9.0 It doesn't work. I already have search the answer on [stackoverflow in mathematica 8.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860616/photo-mosaic-in-mathematica-an-example-from-2008-doesnt-work-in-mathematica-8) . I use the code that [heike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/840947/heike) gave.

```
imagePool =Map[With[{i = Import[#]}, {i, N@Mean[Flatten[ImageData[i], 1]]}] &,FileNames["/Users/xunyanan/Desktop/webwx_img/*.jpg"]];
closeMatch[c_] :=RandomChoice[Nearest[imagePool[[All, 2]] -> imagePool[[All, 1]], c, 20]]
ImageAssemble[Map[closeMatch, ImageData[Import["/Users/xunyanan/Desktop/me.tif"]], {2}]]
```

I think it almost run successfully。
The response screenshot:
[image: out content]

when I clicked “Show Full Output”. I would get the result as below or Mathematica 9.0 exit off-normal
The screenshot:

[image]

I use Mathematica 9.0 right now, have not the experience.so Can anyone suggest a version of this code that works for Mathematica 9? I am appreciated that you can give me some suggest.

Thanks you guys to edit this question. 
My PC ENV : mac OS X version 10.9 and Mathematica 9.0

Comment: @Cole Do you know how to post the question to these guys

Comment: I'm not sure whether you can do that on stack overflow, other than @ mentioning their names

Comment: make sure all images are same color type (make sure Dimensions@Imagedata is all the same)

Comment: in fact it looks like your tiff has an alpha channel. try closematch[#[[1;;3]]&, in Map[]

Comment: @george "same colour type" means black and white ?

Comment: I mean they all need the same number of "channels".  See my other comment i think your tiff is 4 channel ( 3 colors + opacity).  The jpg's are most likely just 3.  If you mix b/w (grayscale) and color that would be a problem as well, ( though often grayscale images are really color with all 3 channels equal. ) .  The fix in my above comment needs one more `]` in front of the `&` by the way..

Comment: You might want to add the `ImageAssemble` part of the code back into your question, in case future seekers wonder why it doesn't work...

Comment: @george you point the issue, I save tiff picture without the alpha channel .It can work

Comment: @cormullion thanks,have changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments note, your problem is because the images you're using for the `imagePool` are not all the same number of channels, and that's upsetting the `Nearest` function. Probably the easy way to fix this is:

```
imagePool = Map[With[{i = Import[#]}, {i, 
  N@Mean[Flatten[ImageData[RemoveAlphaChannel[i]], 1]]}] &, 
    FileNames["*.png", "/tmp"]]
```

i.e. to apply `RemoveAlphaChannel` when you import the images. It would be sensible to apply the same precaution to your source image as well.

Spot the difference:

Before (without `RemoveAlphaChannel`):

[image: before]

After:

[image: after]

Comment: @george Good idea. I have good memories of the original linked Q and A - my first ever StackExchange question... :)

Comment: @cormullion You were a little grasshopper on those days :)